# Android adapters getView() - is parent already measured?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

In my activity, i have a GridView and custom adapter inside onCreate():

```
    GridView vg = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ArrayList<CustomPart> items = ...;
    vg.setAdapter(new TaskVariantsAdapter(this, items));
```

I need to know the actual width of column in GridView to make a special scaling for some images. I noticed that "parent" in getView() is already with non-zero column width - at least im able to get an integer from parent.getColumnWidth().

```
        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ....
           int width = ((GridView) parent).getColumnWidth();
           ....
        }
```

Can i be SURE that parent is already measured and columnWidth is correct? Im asking because (of course) activity has no width and height in onCreate(). I need to know what first adapter.getView() will be AFTER all layout measuring even if i attached adatapter to GridView inside activity.onCreate(). Can you please confirm that?

Comment: I'm playing with gridviews, and the first time getView() is called on the very first element of the grid, the parent (which is the WHOLE gird, no just a cell) always returns getWidth() == 0 and getHeight() == 0 and this is throwing me off.

Thanks for the getColumnWidth!, I was calculating that.